# How not capture a string with regex

Tags: python, html, parsing

i have this string

```
<div class"ewSvNa"><a class="ugP" href="link">Description</a><span data-testid=""><small>$</small><span>0,00</span></div>
```

and this regex `/ewS.*?ugP\".*?f=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<.*?<s.*?n>(.*?)</g`. The result is:

```
Group 1 = 'link'
Group 2 = 'Description'
Group 3 = '0,00'
```

My question is: It`s possible have the result of Group 3 like '$0,00'?

Thank u guys =]]]]]

Comment: No, a group always consists of consecutive characters of the string to process. Gaps are not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommend to not use regex to parse HTML - instead use a proper parser such as [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Then your code becomes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '<div class"ewSvNa"><a class="ugP" href="link">Description</a><span data-testid=""><small>$</small><span>0,00</span></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
amount = soup.select_one('span[data-testid]').get_text()
# '$0,00'
```